# Making each element in an array, an array by itself

Tags: python, arrays, gspread

I'm currently trying to append a list of items into a google sheet. I have scraped a list of items off another google sheet and my list looks like this:

```
arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

however, in order to do a batch update into google sheet, I need to make my list like this:

```
arr = [['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6']]
```

Initially, I thought, at the point of scraping, I will just individually append the array, clear and do it again, like this:

```
arr.append('1')
master_arr.append(arr)
```

output was good, `master_arr` looks like this:

```
master_arr = [['1']]
```

so, I thought I will just clear `arr` by performing `arr.clear()`. But at point of clearing `arr`, my `master_arr` also became like this:

```
master_arr = [[]]
```

so my question is rather simple, how do I get this array?

```
arr = [['1'],['2'],['3'],['4'],['5'],['6']]
```

another alternative of writing to google sheet is to use the for loop as such:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    sheet.update_cell(i+2, 7, arr[i])
```

the only downside to this method is it's super slow and this program may iterate through as many as 10,000 lines once we go into production and it takes about 100 - 3000 milliseconds per iteration and this is not the only column I have to update.

The batch update using a list in the `master_array` format would take a fraction of the time. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: shouldn't be more complicated than `arr = [[x] for x in arr]`

Comment: Wow! Extremely simple, didn't knew about this. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments, you can use a [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
arr = [[item] for item in arr]
```

Another way is using [enumerator](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html):

```
for index, item in enumerate(arr):
    arr[index] = [item]
```

And simple way using [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) & [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
for index in range(len(arr)):
    arr[index] = [item]
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple update

```
arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
for idx, item in enumerate(arr):
    arr[idx] = [item]
```

List comprehension

```
print([[item] for item in arr])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
arr = list(map(list, arr))
```

Comment: if the item in the list is iterable, it will make a list of all the items, instead of keeping the item as it is. Example: `['10']` -> `[['1', '0']]`

Comment: and if the item is not iterable (such as an `int` for example), then it doesn't work at all. So the only situation where it works as apparently intended by the OP is if the list contains only single characters

Comment: @njzk2, yes, you're right. I think, that this code works with list of single-char strings because it's an answer to the question with such as input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numpy,you could do it in this way

```
arr = np.array(['1','2','3','4','5','6'])
```

and then you can reshape the array by

```
arr = np.reshape(arr,(-1,1))
```

I don't how much it is improvement over the other method for a large length array,but you should try it out.

Comment: Using this method will return an error stating that the object is not in a readable JSON. I found my solution above. Thanks for your contribution anyway.

Comment: can you tell me what are you passing in `np.array()`?